# Unable to call server side webmethod function

Tags: jquery, asp.net, webmethod

I am using summernote, I want to upload image to my web server.. Below is my code which I am using

Default.aspx

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#summernote').summernote({
            onImageUpload: function (files, editor, $editable) {
                alert('image?');
                var formData = new FormData();
                formData.append("file", files[0]);

                $.ajax({
                    url: "Default.aspx/UploadImage",
                    data: formData,
                    type: 'POST',
                    cache: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false,
                    success: function (imageUrl) {
                        alert(imageUrl);
                        if (!imageUrl) {

                            // handle error

                            return;
                        }

                        editor.insertImage($editable, imageUrl);
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        alert('error');
                        // handle error
                    }
                });
                console.log('image upload:', files, editor, $editable);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Default.asp.cs

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public static string UploadImage(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        //Saving to Server

        return imageUrl;
    }
```

But it is not calling server side function. Also, alert(imageUrl) is giving me complete page html.

Where I am wrong?

**Updating Question with network information (google chrome)**

[image]

**Edit 2**

Updated after suggestion

**Code**:

```
 url: "About.aspx/UploadImage",
                   data: "multipart/form-data",
                   type: 'POST',
                   cache: false,
                   contentType: "application/json",
```

**Error**:

[image]

*Note: I have changed Page from Default.aspx to about.aspx (but code is same)*

Comment: Check the URL - "Default.aspx/UploadImage", this could be the issue. Inorder to debug further Open chrome network tab (F12) and check the the status code and the response you are getting for the AJAX call.

Comment: Side question, does you class that is holding the method , has property `[ScriptService]` ?

Comment: @abhi I have uploaded my question

Comment: whats the response for the POST call? Also is the 400 bad request part of same call?

Comment: @Holybreath It is in default.aspx.cs page **public partial class _Default : Page**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`WebMethod` or "Page methods" [expect `contentType: "application/json;`](http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/)

Additional ref: [Scott Guthrie - JSON Hijacking and How ASP.NET AJAX 1.0 Avoids these Attacks](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/json-hijacking-and-how-asp-net-ajax-1-0-mitigates-these-attacks):

> There is a built-in validation layer of protection that ASP.NET enforces for both GET and POST based ASP.NET AJAX web methods, which is that regardless of the HTTP verb being used, ASP.NET ***always** requires that the HTTP Content-Type header is set to the value application/json*. It this content type header is not sent, ASP.NET AJAX will reject the request on the server.

- this is why your `alert` is returning the page (html), your call *succesfully* called the `page` (default.aspx), but the `webmethod` was **not** invoked.

See [this for direction/possible solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13322631/304683).

---

I think you're getting confused, probably my fault. I'll try to simplify:

- The suggestion in the link is **not** using WebMethod.
- In order to send file/s, your `contentType` must be `multipart/form-data`

  - see related question: [jquery contentType false](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20863123/304683)
- But as referenced above, WebMethods **require** `contentType` to be `application/json`
- It will not work with WebMethods (hence the link suggests using a generic handler).

Hth...

Comment: Thanks for your answer.. I tried with  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", and also with  contentType: "application/json". but now it is going to error section. Anything else I am wrong with?

Comment: @Zerotoinfinite See the [link above](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13322631/304683) for the possible alternative/solution - re: based on your code it seems you need to send `multipart/form-data` (it won't work with PageMethods)