# jQuery - AJAX - Upload file via FormData isn't working

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, webmethod

The following setup triggers the "success" event, however the response is simply the content of the aspx page.

**HTML**

```html
<input id="fileInput" type="file" />
<button type="button" onclick="UploadFile();">Upload File</button>
```

**Javascript**

```js
function UploadFile() {
    var fileData = new FormData();
    fileData.append('file', $('#fileInput')[0].files[0]);

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'Upload.aspx/IngestFile',
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        data: fileData,
        success: function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        },
        error: function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
}
```

**C#**

```cs
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static string IngestFile()
{
    return "Hello World";
}
```

As far as I can tell, the ajax call is never reaching the WebMethod. As removing the `data` and `processData` ajax properties and using `contentType: 'application/json'` returns the json object `{d: "Hello World"}` as I was hoping for from the original ajax, and hits the breakpoint in the C# code.

Using jQuery 1.8.3.

Tried in Edge 87.0.664.66 and IE11

The only message in the console is the html of the page as loaded

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
...
</html>
```

Comment: As this is more a server side issue (as the JS is correct) I added the relevant server-side tags to the question. I'm not familiar with WebMethods, however I would guess that the issue is because there is no argument to accept the file data in the method signature.

Comment: It would also be worth checking the console in your browser to see if any errors are raised from the AJAX request that you can debug

Comment: As far as I can tell the files are accessed though a property of the `Request` and all examples I have seen have no arguments for the `[WebMethod]`. There is no browser console messages at all other than the html content of the aspx page from the console.log I have added.

Comment: I believe my question to be a duplicate of this one I have since found: [Question from 2016](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40642286/ajax-send-formdata-c-sharp-webmethod). I don't have the points to close this off but I have flagged it as a duplicate (I think).